# JavaScript Printing Questions...

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a system which will print multiple pages, this depends on what sales have been submitted though. So let's say 2 different products have been sold, I need 2 SEPARATE pages to print. I'm under the impression that to do this I will either need to execute "window.print()" twice, which I don't really want to do.

Or I need to create 2 div's which have the height and width set to the size of an A4 piece of paper, correct?

But what if the user then changes the paper to A5, will I have to change the size of the div's to fit A5 or will the print output just shrink down to fit the A5 piece?

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read about CSS *@media print* and *page-break-before* property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Getting_Started/Media).

Comment: Does `@page {margin: 1in;}` overrule the printer settings for the margin? @tetri